# How to combine multiple lists to one?

Tags: python

The question might have been raised before, sorry for that. But I can't find the right solution.

The output of the code below is 3 string lines that are converted to 3 separate lists. I then tried to convert these 3 lists to 1, but couldn't manage it.

Can't check itertools on android and apply the '+' operator here either. The sum doesn't work as well.

```
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['. ', '? ', '! ']
for x in i:
    li = li.replace(x, "&")
    mas = li.split("&")

for x in mas:
    y = x.find("2")
    if y != -1:
        n = x.replace(x, "zzz")
    else: n = x
    t = [n]
    print(t)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a description of what this code is aiming to accomplish.

Comment: Create `t = []` *before the loop* and then `t.append(n)` inside the loop and then `print(t)` *after* the loop…?

Comment: Your code does not seem like it is the optimal way to accomplish what you probably want so if you provide a description maybe we can help you accomplish what you want more elegantly. I definitely recommend checking [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It will help you tremendously

Comment: Please add the desired result. You might want something like `t = ['zzz' if '2' in line else line for line in re.split(r'[.?!]', li) if line]` but without an example what the output should like we can't know.

Comment: My mistake that I didn't include the desired result: ['Text 1', 'zzz', 'Text 3']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something to point out:

```py
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['. ', '? ', '!']
for x in i:
    li = li.replace(x, "&")  
    mas = li.split("&")    # here why are you doing this..? that's an overhed move it out of the loop

for x in mas:
    y = x.find("2")
    if y != -1:
        n = x.replace(x, "zzz")    # and why do you want to replace the whole string instead of assigning the new string to the varaible directly
    else: 
        n = x
    t = [n]    # and this i guess isn't what you wish to do 
    # initialize t = [] just outside the loop and then append to it
    print(t)
```

I am assuming you want an output similar to that follows:

```py
['Text 1', 'zzz', 'Text 3']
```

Fix it this way:

```py
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']
for x in i:
    li = li.replace(x, "&")
    
mas = li.split('&')

t = []
for x in mas:
    if('2' in x):
        t.append("zzz")
    else: 
        t.append(x)
print(t)
```

Or, if you wanted"

```py
['Text 1', 'Text zzz', 'Text 3']
```

Then tweak the 'if' blocks code:

```py
li = 'Text 1. Text 2? Text 3!'
i = ['.', '?', '!']
for x in i:
    li = li.replace(x, "&")
    
mas = li.split('&')

t = []
for x in mas:
    if('2' in x):
        t.append(x.replace('2','zzz'))
    else: 
        t.append(x)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have gotten your code purpose right, you should do sth like:

```py
for index, text in enumerate(mas):
    if '2' in text :
        mas[index] = 'zzz'
```

or

```py
['zzz' if '2' in x else x for x in mas]
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple list into one just do a for loop

```
list = ["one", "two", "three"]
another_list = ["four", "five"]

for number in another_list:
    list.append(number)
print(list)
```

OUTPUT
`['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']`

Comment: Is true, another way of appending lists to list is with the `+` operator applied to 2 or more lists, so the code above would become `sum_list = list+another_list`.